# In FOSUserBundle, how to create an alternative logout

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using FOSUserBundle and Symfony2,

in my site, depending on the roles of the user that is logged in, I want to make the Logout to redirect alternatively to two different pages.

So, I want to do something like this:

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE_PREMIUM") %}
  <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout_premium') }}">{{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">{{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

And then, somehow, do something like this:

```
<route id="fos_user_security_logout" pattern="/logout">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
</route>
<route id="fos_seller_security_logout" pattern="/logoutPremium">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logoutPremium</default>
</route>
```

But, since all in logout is done in `config.yml`, putting all this configuration about login and logout, I don't know how to configure a second trigger and implement it. Actually, the only thing that I want to do is to redirect the user to two different pages according to the role. All the rest should stay the same.

Anything to put around here in `security.yml`?

```
        logout:
          path:   /logout
          target: /main/user
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: one approach that comes to mind is, setting a session variable when the user logs in, that indicates whether the user is a premium member. And when the user logs out, then check in the template if that session variable is true, render the html for premium logout otherwise render html for normal logout..

Comment: Thank you. Thats a solution. I was looking for something more like overriding the controller where de logout is done. But that would work :)

Comment: cool :) i'm glad to be of use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `CustomLogoutHandler` to your `security.yml` configuration.

```
firewalls:
    main: # - the name of your secure area
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
            success_handler: your_bundle.custom_logout_handler
```

Where `your_bundle.custom_logout_handler` would be in charge to logout your user and redirect him according to a similar _target_url parameter for example.

See [`Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout)